# How to grant a Service Principal access to AKS API when RBAC and AAD integration are activated?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-ad-b2b

Upon creating an aks cluster and integrating with azure ad by following instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration, I was able to successfully establish RBAC on azure ad users and user groups.

Unfortunately, this process doesn't work for a service principal created in azure ad

Answer (score 0):

I see a feature request submitted, 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/suggestions/37411549-having-the-ability-to-let-service-principal-non-i